# Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://127.0.0.1

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

i'm trying to create a realtime app with laravel-websockets package, i followed the steps in laravel documents and also the laravel-websockets package and i did all the thing exact the same as docs, but whenever i try to send an event through the channel i receive this error in the browser console:
`Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://127.0.0.1/app/myKey?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.3&flash=false.`

does any body know how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for my case here:

https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/382#issuecomment-631569344

try this out, i hope it works for you too.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is an SSL related problem. Here you are using `wss://` protocol on the localhost. I would suggest you use `ws://` protocol instead of `wss://`.

Hope that this will work.